# Transaction should be small so is this too Long?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Heard that transaction should be small at First I Make an select for update query to lock this row then I update my Datas so is this too Long ?

Update table product

Update table Product Images 30 Images

Update table product Tags 20

Update Table Product Variants 10

Update Table Product Option 7x

So is this too Long ? I Need to Update These rows so idk if this is too Long otherwise I have to redesign my db

I Hope you can give me a good answer

Comment: Put only those statements into a single transaction that need to either all succeed or all fail to ensure consistency.

Comment: all have to succeed because of my consistency, I use shopify webhook so I have to ensure when a product is updated that I updated it on my database too that all data is right

Comment: but is postgresql so fast that he can update 6 tables and more than 30 rows in under 100ms?

Comment: 100ms are a small eternity. If you cannot run 30 small updates in that time, something is wrong with your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is why transactions should be short. It means transactions should take as little time as possible. Why? because transactions take locks, those locks may block other concurrent transactions while those locks are active, and those locks are active while the transaction is open. In this way, large transactions that take much time reduce concurrency.

On the other hand, you might need to enclose several modifications to the database in one single transaction to ensure consistency.

Furthermore, modifying n rows in a single transaction is much faster than modifying n rows in n transactions.

So, you need to decide if you prefer more concurrency o more consistency and more performance.

Another way to approach the problem is trying to optimize the transaction to be as short as possible so that they take as little time as possible. I suggest that you use the following techniques to optimize them:

1. Use set based operations instead of row by row operations.
2. Use proper indexing to avoid full table scans on those set based operations.
3. Use stored procedures to avoid multiple round trips to the database.

I guess your transaction is not large enough to be considered something that will reduce concurrency significantly. Because I think it can be executed in less than 100 milliseconds or so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer! What would you decide? More concurrency or more consistensy ?

Comment: It depends on how long the transaction is. But I think consistency is very important, so the transaction needs to be very large for me to be considered dangerous

Comment: I would also prefer more consistency because I dont want to Angry the Users quantity of a Product. But one question , what are set based operations ? Do you have an example with update ?

Comment: `UPDATE my_table SET my_column = column_value WHERE my_foreign_key_colum = foreing_key_column_value`

Comment: Set based based operations are statements that modify several rows in a single statement

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Is it bad to update my whole row ? Or should I use case and switch when the name is equal then not update name

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting you. What do you mean by updating the whole row?.

Comment: My row has 10 columns, I update all not one, so it is a significant different ?

Comment: @Jsjs best practice is to avoid superfluous updates. I mean only update the row if some of the columns change, do not update a row with the same column values.

Comment: @Jsjs, example to avoid superfluous update: `UPDATE my_table SET colum1 = column1_value, column2 = column2_value WHERE <some condition> AND (colum1 <> column1_value OR column2 <> column2_value)`

Comment: If column1 is nullable it should be: `UPDATE my_table SET column1 = column1_value, column2 = column2_value WHERE <some condition> AND (colum1 <> column1_value OR column1 IS NULL AND column1_value IS NOT NULL OR column1 IS NOT NULL and column1_value IS NULL OR column2 <> column2_value)`

Comment: Nice thank you very much!

Comment: 100 ms is rather long for a transaction.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, what should be the duration of a transaction to be considered not too long?

Comment: @JesúsLópez There is no absolute number; it depends on your situation. "As short as possible."

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, that is what I think, however you said 100ms is rather long for a transaction.

Comment: @JesúsLópez Yes, and I think it is. Note that I said "rather long" and not "oh my god, with long transactions like that your database will die".